# How to Find the Country Name From Untiy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi All I am trying to  find my country name from unity. The Below code works from System. It did not works on iOS. So whats i have to do

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.Networking;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class Location2 : MonoBehaviour
   {
  // Start is called before the first frame update
   public byte[] results;
   public string str2;
   public string[] authorsList;
   public Text text;


void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
    Invoke("F", 3f);
}

public  IEnumerator GetText()
{
    Debug.Log("Get Text");
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/");
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        str2 = www.downloadHandler.text.ToString();
        authorsList = str2.Split(' ');
       
        // Or retrieve results as binary data
    
    }
}

public void F()
{
    text.text = authorsList[25];
// It displays country name 
}


}
```

I dont want use any location based finding. Why the above code did not works on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you can simply assume that your download always is finished after 3 seconds?

Instead of blind trust and invoke the `F` method after hard coded 3 seconds rather wait until the download is actually done:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/"))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            text.text = www.error;
            yield break;
        }

        // Show results as text
        str2 = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }

    authorsList = str2.Split(' ');
       
    F();
}

public void F()
{
    text.text = authorsList.Length >= 26 ? authorsList[25] : "error: no 26 elements";
}
```

---

Then besides that what you get from that API is actually a JSON. So what you rather should do is have a class

```
[Serializable]
public class Root   
{
    public string businessName; 
    public string businessWebsite; 
    public string city; 
    public string continent; 
    public string country; 
    public string countryCode; 
    public string ipName; 
    public string ipType; 
    public string isp; 
    public string lat; 
    public string lon; 
    public string org; 
    public string query; 
    public string region; 
    public string status;  
}
```

And then simply use

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/"))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            text.text = www.error;
            yield break;
        }

        var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(www.downloadHandler.text);

        text.text = root.country;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks derHugo for your reply. But  your code works only on System. It finds country when i works on System. But when i run the  code in iOS -ipad .. It did n't works .. How can  i find the country  name in ios... Shall i have add  any keys in  info.plist....